# Dynamics 365 c# plugin: filtering a lookup fields data

Tags: plugins, microsoft-dynamics

Good evening,

I'm currently working on a plugin that needs to filter a lookup field data returned based on an option set selected value. IE:
Option Set: Automobile Type: Car , Truck or Motorcycle, the lookup field data needs to be filtered by the option set selected. Car: then the lookup field will only display car models or truck is selected then the lookup field will only display truck models ... ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I need to keep away from Javascript if possible..

Thanks
Sal

Comment: So no client side scripting (but why!?), but you want server side code for Filtered data retrieval then You have to use retrievemultiple plugin with lot of performance impact. Still I’m not sure if you can parameterize the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Although is possible to implement the logic with a plugin, in your case I strongly suggest to change the initial option set to a lookup, in this way you can leverage the built-in filtered lookup offered by the platform.